# Call was rejected by callee in the Windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, interop, console-application

I have done an application to create outlook meeting requests automatically. The approach was to create a console application (C#) and schedule it in the windows task scheduler. 
The application is working fine in the Visual Studio and when i double click the exe also it is working fine.

but When i schedule it in the scheduler, im getting the below error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

I was trying to figure this out and did some changes to the DCOM objects. 
I have given permissions to NETWORKSERVICE user and tried to run the scheduler using NETWORKSERVICE user. But no luck so far.

Please help.

Comment: have u checked permission for that particular exe ? and second thing check that with Administrator user rights

Comment: @AshokRathod I have given the permission to the exe. now NETWORKESERVICE user has full permission. But no luck.

Comment: Programmers always look at this error message from the wrong end.  It isn't your program that died, it was the COM server that fell over.  You'll need to find out why *it* suffered a heart attack.  Starting point is the Windows Application event log, hopefully it has an event that has details.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post when researching a similar error.  In my case, TaskScheduler needed to run a console app which in turn read from Outlook 2016.

Finally found that the COM error was tied to TaskScheduler Security Option "Run whether user is logged on or not".  When we changed the option to "Run only when user is logged on", the error disappeared, and the task ran the console app successfully.

Comment: Incidentally, an earlier clue in our case was that the COM class factory error thrown by Task Scheduler could be reproduced if we tried running the console app from a Command Prompt running under administrator credentials.  App runs fine under a normal Command Prompt, but Outlook crashed under the Admin Command Prompt.